# Can't return an array of object with a get function

Tags: c++, pointers, codeblocks

I'm programming a simple blackjack game for a university exam. The game has no graphic, it print everybody on the console.
The project has three classes: Deck, Card, Special Card. I want to show you only the Deck class because it's there my problem.
In Deck class there is a paramater deck which is an array of Cards (array of object) "Card * deck[52]" it's the definition. In the function buildDeck() this array of Card is implemented (every location of the array is filled with different Cards. Now I want to have a function that return this deck so I can use it in the main. I post my code of Deck.h and Deck.cpp

```
DECK.H
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include "Card.h"

class Deck
{
    public:
        Deck();
        void buildDeck();
        void mixDeck();
        Card * getDeck();

    private:
        const char * H = "hearts";
        const char * D = "diamonds";
        const char * C = "clubs";
        const char * S = "spades";
        Card * deck[52];
};

#endif // DECK_H
```

And here it is the .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include "Special_Card.h"
using namespace std;

Deck::Deck(){}

void Deck::buildDeck(){
    //here we got a series of for statements which create the deck 
    //and assign every location of the array to a different card. I 
    //won't post this part to keep the code simple
}

Card * Deck::getDeck(){
    return deck;  //HERE I GOT THE ERROR
}
```

When I try to build the application at the line 57 (the line where I put the comment "//HERE I GOT THE ERROR") I got this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'Card**' to 'Card*' in return
```

Have you got any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use arrays and raw pointers, use std::vector. And does it really make sense for a Deck to contain an array to pointers to Deck?

Comment: This doesn't relate to your error but you already included `Card.h` in your header, so there is no need to include it again in your `.c` file.

Comment: If you want an array of `Card`s use `Card deck[52];` instead of `Card * deck[52];` and if you can use C++11 use `std::array<Card, 52>` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Prefer to have you identifier names differ from variables by more then case.  For example, `Deck` as a type and `deck` as a variable is a poor choice.  A better naming would be `Deck` and `m_deck` as an example.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I would says more `m_cards` than `m_deck` actually.

Comment: "to keep the code simple" It is actually interesting how you did that part. Perhaps a representative fragment.

Comment: `const char * H = "hearts";` It is not very clear why every Deck needs these strings. Aren't they more like global constants?

Comment: `void buildDeck();` You build your object in the constructor. Having a separate build function is problematic.

Comment: `Card * getDeck();` Leaky abstraction. Why is this function needed at all? Your objects must *do* something rather than *have* something. Perhaps `dealCard()` would be an appropriate method.

Comment: you are returning a pointer to Deck but the meber deck is not just a pointer to Deck but an array of objects of type Deck so you can return one of them eg: `return  &deck[0];`

Comment: @Raindrop7: this was also my first try, but it yields error `Cannot initialize return object of type 'Card *' with an rvalue of type 'Card **'`

Comment: aah sorry i did not notice that so just return deck[0] for example as long as deck is an array of  pointers to class Deck

Answer (score 2):

you declared deck as an array of pointers to class Card while you want to return a pointer to class card so you can either return one element from yhe array deck:

```
Card * Deck::getDeck(){
           return deck[0];  // or any other element
 }
```

or if you want to return the whole array of pointers you can declare the function as:

```
Card** Deck::getDeck(){
    return deck;  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question: if you declare member variable `deck`as `Card * deck[52]`, then this denotes an array of 52 pointers to card objects, whereas a signature `Card* getDeck()` indicates a single pointer to a card object, not a pointer to an array of pointers.

Hence, to get rid of the error, you would have to write

```
Card ** getDeck();
```